# How can I find which physical device /dev/console connects to?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, tty

There is a device file called `/dev/console`, whose `(major,minor)` is `(5,1)`.
When I boot with a serial console, it connects to my UART port as `/dev/ttyS0` does.
But when I boot with serial console disabled, the `/dev/console` seems to connect to elsewhere, where `/dev/ttyS0` always connects to the same physical device, namely `UART0`. 
Is there any indication (like something in `/proc` or `/sys`) showing such information? I have tried there but found nothing I want.
I am starting to trace the Linux kernel source to clarify their relationships. 
Can anyone give me some hints? When, where, how and what to determine the physical device to which `/dev/console` connects?

EDIT: The latest finding is that:

1. the `/dev/console` is configured by `console=` of the kernel parameters, which in turn is used by `getty` to open `stdin/stdout/stderr`. If no `console=` is specified, `/dev/null` is opened as `stdin/stdout/stderr`. But I am not sure they are exactly the same with `/dev/console`, which implies `/dev/console` can have its I/O connecting to different physical devices.
2. The `/dev/console` can be read if a USB HID keyboard is plugged and the `console=` is not configured as UART. Therefore `/dev/console` == `/dev/null` seems to make little sense.
   Need more investigations.

Comment: Try looking at how the `console=` parameter is handled from the kernel command line.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked at that and it turns out the parameters are passed to `init` and in turn to `getty_main()`, which is the implementation of `getty` within `busybox`. The relevant part is to `close` the original standard input and then `open` a new one according to the passed parameters. So I am looking for a way which can  retrieve the path from a file descriptor; since I want to know what the 'default' device is if no `console=` specified.

Comment: It seems that the very fist stdin/stdout/stderr opened by `init` is `/dev/null` if no console is specified for `getty`. For those who are interested, it's in `init_main()` -> `console_init()` -> `bb_sanitize_stdio()` of the source of `busybox`.

Comment: Do you have a file `/sys/dev/char/5:1/active`?  It should contain the name of the actual device.

Comment: No, my system doesn't have the file.

Comment: Doesn't "tty" give you it?

Comment: @esperanto IIRC, `tty` would show /dev/console in the case that HID devices are used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/console/active` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such file on my system, which is an ARM-based embedded device. So far what I have learned is that the console can be configured by `/etc/inittab`.

Comment: Inside kernel, whichever is the last module initialized with console= is configured as console. If I understand correctly then inittab is used to configure which tty terminal will be used to run login program.

Comment: FYI Linux 2.6.35 doesn't have the file, some newer Linux systems have it.

Comment: On my desktop linux, this shows `tty0` and then `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active` shows `tty7` and `tty7` is my X server.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I believe that means that `tty7` is the active VC, but that `/dev/console` output goes to `tty0`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: How so? It just means that `/dev/console` is set to go to `/dev/tty0` (which means the current VC), but it doesn't have to be set up that way.

Comment: Currently on my system, `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/console/active` says tty0, and `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active` says tty7. Then this probably means that both are pointing to tty7 in the end.

Answer (score 1):

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console.4.html :
       "The current console is also addressed by
       /dev/console or /dev/tty0, the character device with major number 4
       and minor number 0."

I hope that was what you were looking for.